# Can anyone suggest a way to inifnite scroll of google search reseult python selenium

Tags: python, dictionary, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have tried below code but it's not working. This was previously suggested by someone here. But don't works.

```
def load_companies(self, url):
    print("Getting business info", url)
    self.driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    panel_xpath = '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]'
    scrollable_div = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, panel_xpath)
    # scrolling
    flag = True
    i = 0
    while flag:
        print(f"Scrolling to page {i + 2}")
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable_div)
        time.sleep(2)

        if "You've reached the end of the list." in self.driver.page_source:
            flag = False

        self.get_business_info()
        i += 1
```

Solution for infinite scroll of google maps in python selenium

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please describe your exact error/issue ? include trace / error message if any. And try to include a complete working code example of your issue so we can reproduce it. see [MRE] and take a [Tour]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this lines helps you. I didn't have enough time, so sorry for not adding comments for my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
#a testing url
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=war&oq=war&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQABiABDIHCAIQABiABDIHCAMQABiABDIHCAQQABiABDIHCAUQABiABDINCAYQLhjHARjRAxiABDIGCAcQRRg90gEHNTgyajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
body = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body")
while True:
    old_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == old_height:
        break
more_bottom = driver.find_element(By.ID, "botstuff").find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "span")
for index in range(len(more_bottom)-1, -1, -1):
    if more_bottom[index].text == 'More results':
        more_bottom = more_bottom[index]
        break
max_try = 4
while not not True:
    try_number = 0
    while True:
        try:
            more_bottom.click()
            break
        except:
            if try_number > max_try:
                try_number = -1
                break
            time.sleep(1.5)
            try_number += 1
    if try_number == -1:
        break
    time.sleep(1.5)
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
```